# Android Pop up window

Tags: android, popupwindow

I looked online and was not able to find a working example of the `PopupWindow` class. The code examples I found online either compile but do not work, or are using methods which have since been removed (such as `Activity.getViewInflate()`).

Is there a simple working example that displays a PopupWindow?

Comment: Hello, did you tried this one? http://www.ceveni.com/2009/09/popup-window-in-android-sample-program.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be AlertDialog can solve your problem you can full screen dialog window it just look like a window it is an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Any Activity can be a "popup window" it just has to show up on top of the previous activity and not take up all the screen real estate! :)

Here's an example of how this works...

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Or are you just looking for an Alert that gets dismissed by being touched anywhere (rather than with an "OK" button?

Comment: i am using an activity with background as transparent and whose layout parameters are half of the window size what i want to do is disable background activity when this activity is shown.